# Flexdashboard+Shiny rmd file won't render the html. Website can't be updated with shiny interactivity

Tags: html, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I created a flexdashboard + shiny dashboard contains multiple interactive maps and deployed it as a page through GitHub. Initially, I only used the regular flexdashboard and the GitHub page works well. Then I decided to add sliderinput/selectinput option and added runtime: shiny on my yaml header. Since then, while I can clink run document and the website popped up just fine in my local, my index.html won't rendered inside my project directory. Instead it says

Output created: /private/var/folders/kg/v028pmqj55xd3yhk3ktvc57m0000gn/T/RtmpCYyI1K/fileb77d6b31d1aa/index.html

When I copied this file to my project directory and pushed it to GitHub, my page still is not updated to the latest index.rmd version.

Can somebody please help to solve this?

Data & index.rmd file are in this my GitHub repo: https://github.com/merlyklaas/capstone

Thank you!!!

I want to deploy my dashboard on GitHub page.

Comment: You can't serve a shiny powered dashboard via Github pages. To this end you need a shiny server running in the background. See e.g. https://www.shinyapps.io for one option.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment! I've been trying to deploy it just using Github pages and finally I found this useful tutorial to deploy my index.rmd file to shinyapps.io right away https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6BFGdLCOXs.